# HearthRateMonitor/BT101 Sample in Swift: discoverServices's delegate methods not called

Tags: delegates, swift, core-bluetooth

[over here (GitHub link)](https://github.com/stuffmc/BT101MacSwift/blob/master/BT101Mac/ViewController.swift#L34)  I'm trying to "follow/reproduce" the HearthRateMonitor sample in Swift. All is fine until "discoverServices(nil)" which isn't calling any of my delegate methods.

Specifically, where

```
[aPeripheral discoverServices:nil];
```

in ObjC (See [TimBurk's iOS Mirror of HRM @ GitHub](https://github.com/timburks/iOSHeartRateMonitor/blob/master/HRM/HeartRateViewController.m#L142)), this Code in Swift

```
peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
```

(Mine), isn't calling any of the delegate methods

Any Idea? FYI I've also posted this in the [Core Bluetooth](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1020207#1020207) and [Swift](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/240022) DevForums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your behavior is different from the original code. You need to retain the peripheral. See: https://github.com/timburks/iOSHeartRateMonitor/blob/dc8c186d7838aaad47345baf89a4f2c2b29ff5c7/HRM/HeartRateViewController.m#L127

Comment: Yup. I had to keep a reference to the peripheral (duh!). I changed the code here: https://github.com/stuffmc/BT101MacSwift/commit/1a5a818d91bd4633c5782b4200b60e4a9f87bc1b